# Delay not working as first time work

Tags: jquery

First of all i want to say the requirement of the code. I want to add class on each time and just remove the same class after some sec. So i have done like this

```
var stops = [35,30,25,20,15,10];

$.each(stops, function(index, value){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $( ".progress-bar" ).css( "width", value + "%" ).attr( "aria-valuenow", value ); 
        $('.decalir span').html( (value/5) ).addClass('change').delay(1500).
              queue(function() {
                  jQuery('.decalir span').removeClass('change');
              });
    }, index * 5000);
});
```

But it is working for the first time. then it is not working after first time, means dont remove the class.

Please see the HTML

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
    <span class="sr-only">0% Complete</span>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to pass in the ´next´ variable in your queue function. Here's how you need to do it.

```
var stops = [35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10];

$.each(stops, function(index, value) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".progress-bar").css("width", value + "%").attr("aria-valuenow", value);
    $('.decalir span').html((value / 5)).addClass('change').delay(1500).
    queue(function(next) {
      jQuery('.decalir span').removeClass('change');
      next();
    });
  }, index * 5000);
});
```

I did a slight change in your code just to see the effect here: https://jsfiddle.net/qbkt33bx/18/

This is from the documentation at https://api.jquery.com/queue/

> As of jQuery 1.4, the function that's called is passed another function as the first argument. When called, this automatically dequeues the next item and keeps the queue moving.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the jQuery code to this

```
var stops = [35,30,25,20,15,10];
$.each(stops, function(index, value){
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 10000;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $( ".progress-bar" ).css( "width", value + "%" ).attr( "aria-valuenow", value ); 
        $('.decalir span').html( '<span class="change">'+(value/5) + '</span>').delay(1500).
              queue(function() {
                  jQuery('.decalir span').removeClass('change');
              });
    }, index * rand);
});
```

And it is working. But the only problem is creating a span in the span. But it is ok, if use a p tag instead of span.